# Regex how to check only 1 character behind and whole word at the same time

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds

I have find `(?i)(?<!a|e|i|o|u)(\w)led` and replace with `$1lled`

Words are canceled fulfilled initialed paralleled

Results:

```
cancelled correct
fulfilled correct
initialled correct
parallelled incorrect
```

I need the whole word paralleled checked so it produced paralleled and not just "if there is a vowel before led". I've tried various combinations and it just won't work.

Also i need to cover words with upper case ie. CANCELED.

Comment: There are no rules defined in this question to exclude manipulating `led` in `paralleled` and I think there couldn't be anyone.

Comment: Your regex doesn’t check if there’s a vowel before “led”; it checks if there’s a vowel before the letter that’s before “led”. Please clarify.

Comment: Isn't this not going to work? There's bound to be more exceptions: OLED, oiled, etc. Anyway, although Notepad++ has a non-standard Regex engine, something like `(?!parall)` may be used to exclude specific prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

Specify an exception for paralleled:

```
(?i)(?<!a|e|i|o|u)(\w)led(?<!paralleled)
```

Comment: If your answer is bound to the very specific given example words in the question so how about [`(?<!le|l)led`](https://regex101.com/r/Y3n1Id/1)?

Comment: @revo Your answer worked. I added |oi inside () to eliminate the rest of the words that don't require lled. Perhaps you should create your own answer so i can upvote it. Now i need to cover both lower and upper case.